# showing foreign key relationship in model class using ICollection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model, foreign-keys

I have a model class which has foreign key relationship,

```
public class AppointmentModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AppointmentTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int AppointmentRoom { get; set; }            
    
    [ForeignKey("VisitorId")]
    public VisitorModel Visitors { get; set; } 
    public int VisitorId { get; set; }  
}

public class VisitorModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int VisitorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string VisitorName { get; set; }
    public int VisitorAddr { get; set; } 
}
```

But I have found defining foreign key class as `ICollection`. What is the difference in both the declaration types? Which one should we use?

```
[ForeignKey("VisitorId")]
public ICollection<VisitorModel> Visitors { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Which one you should use depends if you need a 1:1 relationship or a 1:n relationship.

Since each AppointmentModel has one VisitorId there will be one Visitor(no s) per AppointmentModel. So the navigationproperty is a single instance and no collection.