# convert two LINQ queries to single query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have made two LINQ queries one for getting `Id` and another for getting `amount` from the same model class. Since I am new to `LINQ` I don't know whether these two queries can be combined and get the same result.

```
var KID = db.Nikashas.Where(n => n.NIKASHAId == id).Select(n => n.KaryakramId).FirstOrDefault();
var KAMT = db.Nikashas.Where(n => n.NIKASHAId == id).Select(n => n.NikashaAmount).FirstOrDefault();
int kid = Convert.ToInt32(KID);
decimal kamt = Convert.ToDecimal(KAMT);
```

Both the above queries give the same row only selected fields are different. So is there any way I can use one single query to retrieve both the values and then how to convert `KaryakramId` to `int` and `NikashaAmount` to `decimal`?

Comment: Why aren't you saving the id and amounts in the db as an integer and decimal value?  You shouldn't convert data to another type, like string, when saving it to a DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, assuming that your values are returned as strings and will be valid when converted to their types, and that the nikasha object is not too big that returning the whole thing adversely affects performance:

```
var nikasha = db.Nikashas.Where(n => n.NIKASHAId == id).FirstOrDefault();

//to handle a default null, check for null
if(nikasha != null)
{
    int KID = int.Parse(nikasha.KaryakramId);
    decimal KAMT = decimal.Parse(nikasha.NikashaAmount);
}
```

Comment: Please see this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508302/showing-foreign-key-relationship-in-model-class-using-icollection

Answer (score 4):

You can use projection and assign it on anonymous type:

```
var KID = db.Nikashas.Where(n => n.NIKASHAId == id).Select(n => new { karya = n.KaryakramId, nika = n.NikashaAmount }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then from there you can access it via properties of your anonymous type:

```
int kid = Convert.ToInt32(KID.karya);
decimal kamt = Convert.ToDecimal(KID.nika);
```

Comment: Please see this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508302/showing-foreign-key-relationship-in-model-class-using-icollection

Answer (score 2):

The required data can be accessed with `FirstOrDefault()` extension and assign to anonymous type as:

```
var result = db.Nikashas
              .FirstOrDefault()(n => n.NIKASHAId == id)
              .Select(n => new 
               { 
                  kId = n.KaryakramId,
                  kAmt = n.NikashaAmount 
               });
```

From the `result`, required values can be accessed from anonymous type:

```
int kid = Convert.ToInt32(result.kId);
decimal kamt = Convert.ToDecimal(result.kAmt);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = db.Nikashas.Where(n => n.NIKASHAId == id)
    .Select(n => new { 
        kid = Convert.ToInt32(n.KaryakramId),  
        kamt = Convert.ToDecimal(n.NikashaAmount)}).FirstOrDefault();

int kid = res.kid;
decimal kamt = res.kamt;
```

Comment: Please see this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508302/showing-foreign-key-relationship-in-model-class-using-icollection

Comment: the link is not an answer, it's another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use select new object with some property that you want

```
var result = db.Nikashas.Where(n => n.NIKASHAId == id).Select(n => new { n.KaryakramId, n.NikashaAmount}).FirstOrDefault();
```